# In metric space (X,d) the effect of d where d is distance function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have  little bit knowledge  about  metric spaces . Like definitions and just check which one is metric space or not   using definition.  But now I am not satisfy with that . I  want
To know  if  $(\mathbb{R},e)$ is metric space with $e(x,y) =|x-y|$    and if I change   it to $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d (x,y) = \frac{e(x,y)} { 1+e (x,y)}$  then  what is difference in both and why ?     Tell about compactness, connectedness , completeness  etc .  In another words I want to now the effects of     $d$ in metric $(X,d)$ . Please  help me ..

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: Then tell me a good book on metric space please

Comment: Likely any introductory book on topology would suffice; I personally like Munkres as an introductory text and Willard as a slightly more advanced book.

Comment: @Clayton First of all, "it's a lot like homework" is not in itself a good reason to close the question.  Second, having read through Munkres and some introductory analysis texts, I've never seen a question of this particular variety.  While it is common to ask to verify that $d$ is a metric, it is uncommon to ask about the properties of the resulting space.

Comment: There are many questions here, it might be more effective to split your question into several.  First, the question about $d$ and $e$ being metrics - do you know the definition of a metric?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I didn't vote to close the question (I'm not sure if anyone had at the point in time in which you made your statement, but it has since been withdrawn if such a vote had been cast). Neither did I downvote the question, I've only made a statement that it sounds a lot like homework (which I'll stand by). As for the book recommendation, I think it is natural to look at basic open sets and attempt to determine said properties (problems like this do arise in Munkres).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't very much which is different between the spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X,e)$.  In particular, note that the resulting spaces are the same toplogically since the map $\phi:(X,e) \to (X,d)$ given by $\phi(x) = x$ is a *homeomorphism*.  That is, $\phi$ is continuous, as is its inverse.  However, the metrics are not [topologically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) in the usual sense since, for example, $e(1,y)/d(1,y)$ can be made arbitrarily large.

So, $(X,d)$ and $(X,e)$ will necessarily share all topological properties.  For instance, $X$ will be non-compact and connected under both metrics.

There are some differences, though.  For example, note that $(X,d)$ is *bounded*, while $(X,e)$ is not.

Notably, both spaces are complete (although completeness is *not* generally preserved by homeomorphism).  In particular, it suffices to note that the map $\phi:(X,e) \to (X,d)$ preserves limits **and** Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Two  more Qeustion  occurs in my mind i.e  if some one ask me  ((01),d) is complete or not ?  then can I discuss  it as subset of  (R, d).  As ( R , d ) Is complete  and (01) is not closed in R so not complete  where d (x,y) =|x-y|   and   If (X,d1 ) is metric space with bounded metric  d1 then every subset  of it is bounded  .

Comment: @guronkar I don't see any question to answer in your comment